# How to copy a set of object to an array of object?

Tags: c++, arrays, iterator, set

I have to copy the first size element from a set of Solution (a class) named population to an array of solution named parents. I have some problems with iterators because i should do an hybrid solution between a normal for loop
and a for with iterators. The idea is this: when I'm at the ith iteration of the for I declare a new iterator that's pointing the beginning
of population, then I advance this iterator to the ith position, I take this solution element and I copy into parents[i]

```
Solution* parents;   //it is filled somewhere else
std::set<Solution> population;   //it is filled somewhere else
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    auto it = population.begin();
    advance(it, i);
    parents[i] = *it;
}
```

Two error messages popup with this sentence: 'Expression: cannot dereference end map/set iterator'
and 'Expression: cannot advance end map/set iterator'
Any idea on how to this trick? I know it's kinda bad mixing array and set, i should use vector instead of array?

Comment: Is it acceptable to copy the elements to a `std::vector` instead of an array?  It makes the code on line long if you use a `std::vector`.

Comment: It's not clear what are you trying to achieve. Why do you advance on every iteration instead of simply iterating?

Comment: Yea it's kinda bad, I want to take the element from the set and put into the array. The problem is that array can use integer index in a for loop while set work with iterator.

Answer (score 1):

You use `std::copy_n`.

```
#include <algorithm>

extern Solution* parents;   //it is filled somewhere else
extern std::set<Solution> population;   //it is filled somewhere else

std::copy_n(population.begin(), size, parents);
```

Comment: Yes that works. Also I had some big problem because I wasn't initializing population, so it was copying from an empty set to a non empty array. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> I have to copy the first size element from a set [..] to an array

You can use `std::copy_n`.

---

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    auto it = population.begin();
    advance(it, i);
```

The problem with this is that you're iterating over the linked list in every iteration. This turns the copy operation from normally linear complexity to quadratic.

---

> Expression: cannot dereference end map/set iterator'

The problem here appears to be that your set doesn't contain at least `size` number of elements. You cannot copy `size` number of elements if there aren't that many. I suggest that  you would copy less elements when the set is smaller.

---

> i should use vector instead of array?

Probably. Is the array very large? Is the size of the vector not known at compile time? If so, use a vector.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `size` may be incorrectly set. To ensure that your code behaves as expected, you should just use the collection's size directly:

```
auto it = population.begin();
for (int i = 0; i < population.size(); i++) {
    parents[i] = *it;
    ++it;
}
```

This can also be solved with a much simpler expression:

```
std::copy(population.begin(), population.end(), parents);
```

Comment: This solution works. The problem is that I don't have to copy all the set population into the array parents, but i have to copy the first size element of population into the array parents